# Socket 10048 response after socket.connect_ex

Tags: python, sockets, bind

I have this little piece of code that returns a `10048` after printing the response

I have tried adding `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` and it did help for the first time. After running the program for the first time it prints 0. Which from my knowledge means the port is open, but after that it returns `10048`. I have also tried changing the port.

This is my code:

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1024
s.bind((host,port))
result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
print(result)
s.close()
```

I am not sure why it is returning this. I have looked everywhere but cant find an answer. I am trying to get it to return either 0 or 1. That why I can tell if the port is open or closed.

Comment: You don't need to bind a client socket. Just connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work when host is the local machine: you try to use the same port on same machine as both source and destination.

You must either use two different ports, or different machines on do not fix the source port and let the system choose one (do not bind before connect).